# Deriving hyperbolic functions

Tags: complex-numbers

If $\tan(\theta+i\phi)$=$\sin(\alpha+i\beta)$, prove that $\sin 2\theta\cot\alpha=\sinh 2\phi\coth\beta$.

I tried taking $\tan(\theta-i\phi)=\sin(\alpha-i\beta)$ and then I found $\tan(\theta+i\phi-\theta+i\phi)$. But I couldn't proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(\alpha+i\beta)+\sin(\alpha-i\beta)=\tan(\theta+i\phi)+\tan(\theta-i\phi)$$

$$\iff2\sin\alpha\cosh\beta=\dfrac{\sin2\theta}{\cos(\theta+i\phi)\cos(\theta-i\phi)}$$

Find  $$\sin(\alpha+i\beta)-\sin(\alpha-i\beta)=\tan(\theta+i\phi)-\tan(\theta-i\phi)$$

Now divide